# How can I check Internet access using a Bash script on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, wifi, ping

In my school, the Internet is not available (every night after 23:00 the school will kill the Internet connection, to put us to bed >..<), Then the ping will never stop, though I have used the parameter `ping -w1 ...`.

That is, when I use: `ping -q -w1 -c1 8.8.8.8` to check if the Internet connection is up/down, it will be there without any output and doesn't exit, just like I am using a single `cat`.

I don't know why it's like this, But I think the problem is related to the *school-internet-service*. Any suggestion? (I think `wget` may be a good alternative, but how can I use it?)

Comment: this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-a-internet-connection-in-bash?rq=1

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using `wget`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you very much! My old version lacks a `--tries`, thus it doesn't work.

Comment: Personally, I enhance this pattern by making this `wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null`. That throws away the output, which means that files aren't left lying around, and there aren't any problems with write permissions.

Comment: You really should use `--spider` option as it will send a http `HEAD` request as opposed to a http `GET` request. Now, in this case you're checking against google.com which is a pretty light weight page so it may be ok as it is. But as a general rule you should use a `HEAD` request if you just want to check if something is available without actually *downloading* it. I've added to the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 23):

If the school actually turns off their router instead of redirecting all traffic to a "why aren't you in bed" page, then there's no need to download an entire web page or send HTTP headers. All you have to do is just make a connection and check if someone's listening.

```
nc -z 8.8.8.8 53
```

This will output "Connection to 8.8.8.8 port 53 [tcp/domain] succeeded!" and return a value of 0 if someone's listening.

If you want to use it in a shell script:

```
nc -z 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1
online=$?
if [ $online -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi
```

Comment: This is the fastest approach, it pings the dns server instead of getting google's website data. thumbs up.

Comment: might be good to use a timeout here nc -z -w 5 8.8.8.8 53 >/dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERNET_STATUS="UNKNOWN"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`
while [ 1 ]
 do
    ping -c 1 -W 0.7 8.8.4.4 > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [ "$INTERNET_STATUS" != "UP" ]; then
            echo "UP   `date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z` $((`date +%s`-$TIMESTAMP))";
            INTERNET_STATUS="UP"
        fi
    else
        if [ "$INTERNET_STATUS" = "UP" ]; then
            echo "DOWN `date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z` $((`date +%s`-$TIMESTAMP))";
            INTERNET_STATUS="DOWN"
        fi
    fi
    sleep 1
 done;
```

The output will produce something like:

```
./internet_check.sh

UP   2016-05-10T23:23:06BST 4
DOWN 2016-05-10T23:23:25BST 19
UP   2016-05-10T23:23:32BST 7
```

The number in the end of a line shows duration of previous state, i.e. 19 up, 7 seconds down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Had lots of ups and downs in a few minutes. While DropBox was online and surfing the web was possible... See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190610/19694 where they mention `nc` would be better to use than ping as quite a few hosters disable ICMP as well.

Comment: I fail to see how I would get the duration with the code above.  I tried it and the 'duration' for each line grew monotonically.  Doesn't TIMESTAMP have to be reset each time through the loop?

Answer (score 3):

**Without wget**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the timeout option `-t`:

```
ping -q -t 5 -w1 -c1 8.8.8.8 t
```

Comment: one problem with this solution is, that some networks might block outgoing pings (my uni had a famous record for doing so). it doesn't seem the be the case with the OP though.

Comment: @umlaeute, in that case you may use `wget http://google.com` or even (better & simpler) `curl`

Answer (score 2):

Install fping: > fewer problems than *ping*.

```
fping google.com | grep alive
```

To use, for example, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

itest=$(fping google.com | grep alive)

while [ "$itest" == "" ]
        do
        sleep 5
        itest=$(fping google.com | grep alive)
done
echo now online
```

Comment: `fping` would need to be installed before running the example.

Answer (score 2):

Using the example above. I wrote this script to log the state of your connection:
https://gist.github.com/cganterh/ffc2fffa8263857cbece

First, save the following code into a `name.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo $(date) "1" | tee -a log.csv
    else
        echo $(date) "0" | tee -a log.csv
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Then, execute `name.sh` file in terminal, and then check the log state information in `log.csv` of the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

## Reliable old `ping` in a separate Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr='8.8.8.8' # Google's public DNS server
[[ -z `ping -c1 $ipaddr |& grep -o 'Network is unreachable'` ]] || exit 1
[[ -z `ping -c3 $ipaddr |& grep -o '100% packet loss'` ]] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

---

Put this in a separate script. It will handle **different network situations** as (1) not being connected to a network, (2) connected to the network, but cannot access the Internet (or at least Google), and (3) connected to the Internet.

---

You may later use the `exit code` of the script to check connectivity, e.g.

```
~$ script-name && echo online || echo offline
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to combine a few of the previous answers, so I could later create a plot showing ups, downs, and their durations:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# pinger is a bash shell script that monitors the network
# status every 15 seconds and records if it is up '1' or down '0'
# into the file log.csv from whence it may be plotted.
#
# author: J. W. Wooten, Ph.D.
# since: 11/12/2019
# version: 1.0
#
TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`
while [ 1 ]
  do
    nc -z -w 5 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1
online=$?
    TIME=`date +%s`
    if [ $online -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z` 1 $(($TIME-$TIMESTAMP))" | tee -a log.csv
    else
      echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z` 0 $(($TIME-$TIMESTAMP))" | tee -a log.csv
    fi
    TIMESTAMP=$TIME
    sleep 15
  done;
```

This outputs to a CSV file every 15 seconds.  Using Excel or Numbers, you can read the file and create a plot which will show when the Internet connection was not available and also the duration.  If it changes from your sleep interval, then it is spending time trying to connect. I hope to add the ability to send me a text when it detects network is down next.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [Majal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291233/how-can-i-check-internet-access-using-a-bash-script-on-linux/39323006#39323006) is just to test the return code from ping, which returns 0 if the site responds, 1 if there is no reply and 2 if the network is unreachable.

```
    ping -c 1 -t 5 8.8.8.8 2&>1
    rc=$?
    [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] && { echo "Connected to the Internet" ; exit 0 ; } \
 || [[ $rc -eq 1 ]] && { echo "No reply from Google DNS" ; exit 1 ; } \
 || [[ $rc -eq 2 ]] && { echo "Network unreachable" ; exit 2 ; }
```

Using ping has the advantage of not needing to download anything, improving the speed of the test.