# Using git as backup tool with cron and ssh aliases

Tags: git, ssh, cron, alias

I have a repository for storing all my configs (e. g. .ssh/config). From time to time I need a backup them, so I need to run these commands

```
git commit -am 'Auto git backup `date -I`'
git push origin master
```

It is pretty annoying so I decided to make a cron job, which runs simple script with these lines above. I ran `crontab -e` and added new line at the end of file. I also replaced `git` with `which git` inside of script. `git commit` command works perfectly in contrast with `git push`. When I made some debug prints I got

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I run script manually, it works. I think it is because of SSH aliases in my `.ssh/config`, which looks like

```
Host     bitbucket.org-personal
HostName bitbucket.org
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host    bitbucket.org-work
HostName bitbucket.org
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_id_rsa
```

Does somebody have idea, how to propagate SSH aliases to environment, which runs cron jobs? Also maybe I am wrong and problem is caused by something else.

Comment: You miss how the line you wrote into the crontab look like. Are you sure the backup is run when the network is up?

Comment: Line in crontab is `@reboot /home/user/scripts/backup-and-commit.sh` and I added some debug messages and I'm sure cron job works as I want. Do you think it doesn't push commits because of network issues?

Comment: Yes. The error is obvious that you do not have network. Try to postpone the run some minutes to wait for the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a network connection. When I added sleep (or modified solution from here [How to check internet access using bash script in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291233/how-to-check-internet-access-using-bash-script-in-linux)) at the begging of the script, it works perfectly.