# Error deploying meteor app

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I get the following error during the verifying deployment stage of deploying a meteor app

[image]

The full log is a long list of similar errors of fetch failed ending with

[image]

Comment: Can you please post more information? Such as, if you are using Meteor Up (which I presume you are), what your mup.js file looks like?

Comment: @Kyle Yes I am using meteor up. Is there anything specific from mup.js you want to know? It used to work fine and I have made no changes to the file since

Comment: seems like your network is having problems connecting to registry.npmjs.org. maybe you should debug your network.

Comment: @williamli do you mean the network I am deploying from or the network the server is on?

Comment: I don't have access to all of your log and I am not 100% sure how MeteorUp handles it. In theory, mup will call meteor build and builds a nodejs app and transfer it over to a server. Somewhere during this build process, it will call npm install to pull in all the dependencies (not sure if it is done on your local computer, in a docker container, or in the server). but i am pretty sure the error you are seeing comes from this npm install process and it is failing because it cannot connect to registers.npmjs.org

Comment: can you provide the full deployment log?

Comment: @williamli [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Cld.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhAfP.png)

Comment: @Joe i meant the whole of your deployment log. like from the start to the point it hit this error.

Comment: @williamli where can I get that from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148517/discussion-between-williamli-and-joe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by restarting the docker service

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719701)

> restarting docker with this command fixes it for me but I don't know why
>
> `sudo service docker restart`

I too, have no idea why that worked