# docker npm install error getaddrinfo enotfound registry npmjs org-registry-npmj [Docker for Windows]

Tags: windows, docker, minikube

Hi I have similar problem to this:
[docker npm install Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515203/docker-npm-install-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmj)

But I use Docker for Windows, and can't find a workaround for my issue.
I also use it with Minikube.
I try to build my image on Minikube with steps like this:

1. eval $(minikube docker-env)
2. docker build -t app-frontend .

and I get response like below:

```
Step 6/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 8275f15b4a16
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon failed, reason:                    getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-19T18_46_29_669Z-debug.log
```

I don't know how to use it.
https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

I found my DNS servers are in Ipv6

```
ipconfig /all | findstr /R "DNS\ Servers"
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:730:3ed2:1000::53
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
```

But  after I try use one of that DNS I got this:

```
$ docker run --dns  fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1 busybox nslookup google.com
invalid argument "fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1" for "--dns" flag: fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1 is not an ip address
```

I'm stuck I can't find anything on the Internet, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you ping something outside your network i.e `$ ping 8.8.8.8`. Did you try to restart docker `sudo service docker restart`? Are you using any proxy or firewall? How did you install `Minikube`? Did you base on k8s docs? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/ ?

Comment: Reinstall Hyper-V and minikube helps