# Ping Command inside docker container doesnt work

Tags: linux, networking, docker, ping

I can ping an IP from host box (Linux centos rhel 7.2) but when I do the same inside docker container, it fails to respond.

[root@f321ef079128]# ping 10.254.19.46
PING 10.254.19.46 (10.254.19.46) 56(84) bytes of data.

What can be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Let me ask you this. Are you able to ping your Docker container from the host?

Comment: Yes I could. Inside container, I couldn't ping google.com as well. looks like internet connectivity is disabled. how to enable that?

Comment: I highly doubt it's an internet issue as your connectivity to host itself does not go through. Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1 from inside the container?

Comment: [root@f321ef079128]# ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms

Comment: OK, so no issue with n/w card. What container image is this? Is iptables enabled?

Comment: @RuncyOommen docker restart fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

[My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Top suggestions seems to be to restart the docker service:

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: then should be makred as duplicated instead of adding your answer, @mattjtyas.

Answer (score 2):

i think you dont have internet acces in container.
Try run your container with:

```
docker run --dns **your_dns** ...
```