# What is correct working IBM repository for Liberty profile docker image

Tags: dockerfile, websphere-liberty

I am trying to build docker image with Liberty profile.Using below location Docker file.

https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/blob/master/ga/developer/kernel/Dockerfile

```
FROM ibmjava:8-jre

RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#Install WebSphere Liberty

ENV LIBERTY_VERSION 16.0.0_03

ARG LIBERTY_URL

ARG DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS=""

RUN LIBERTY_URL=${LIBERTY_URL:-$(wget -q -O - https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/index.yml  | grep $LIBERTY_VERSION -A 6 | sed -n 's/\s*kernel:\s//p' | tr -d '\r' )}  \
        && wget $DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS $LIBERTY_URL -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O /tmp/wlp.zip \
        && unzip -q /tmp/wlp.zip -d /opt/ibm \
        && rm /tmp/wlp.zip

ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH

# Set Path Shortcuts
ENV LOG_DIR=/logs \
        WLP_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ibm/wlp/output

RUN mkdir /logs \
        && ln -s $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/defaultServer /output \
        && ln -s /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer /config

# Configure WebSphere Liberty
RUN /opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server create \
        && rm -rf $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/.classCache /output/workarea

COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/

EXPOSE 9080 9443

CMD ["/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server", "run", "defaultServer"]**
```

When I build docker image using this code we are getting error like below.Looks like this repository is not active now.Can anyone provide valid repository.

> CWWKF1219E: The IBM WebSphere Liberty Repository cannot be reached. Verify that your computer has network access and firewalls are configured correctly, then try the action again. If the connection still fails, the repository server might be temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is correct.

As the error message indicates, try checking your network config. To do that you can try to reach this link in a web browser. (this URL is simply from the script)
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/index.yml

Also, you could testing your connection to the repository outside of the docker environment by doing:

```
$WLP_HOME/bin/installUtility testConnection
```

If you are able to ping the repo from your computer, but not within the docker container, then perhaps your [docker container has no internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet).

To fix the "docker can't access internet" issue, it looks like the solution from the above link was to do:

```
service docker restart
```