# Force use of DNS in OpenShift OKD

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to use the `oc cluster up` command on Ubuntu 18.04. This Ubuntu 18.04 is also a Vagrant virtual machine with default Vagrant NAT networking.

Default `oc cluster up` will start cluster without internet connectivity. So most if not all application will fail in various ways.

For example the Apache example will fail with message that github cannot be resolved.

> error: fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/openshift/httpd-ex.git/': Could not resolve host:
>   github.com; Unknown error

Found example here [Unable to resolve github.com from OpenShift origin pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526628/unable-to-resolve-github-com-from-openshift-origin-pods) but that doesn't fix the problem.

Is there a way to make the OpenShift cluster use a specifig DNS? I tried `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

> {
>           "dns": ["208.67.222.222"]
>
> }

and

> {
>           "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
>
> }

All these settings do nothing / not much.