# Docker not able to ping by name on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I'm pretty new with docker and windows containers so with every issue I have a lot of problems to solve it.

I don't no why and how to set docker to ping by name on windows 10.

When I run command

**docker run dockerimage ping google.com**

get response

**Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.**

and when I run command

**docker run dockerimage ping 8.8.8.8**

get valid response.

I think this makes me a problem when I want to download file from my application that runs on docker container.

So if anyone know how to solve it, I would be more than grateful.

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: What's there in your docker image?

Comment: MS Dynamics NAV

Comment: I tried "docker run centos ping google.com" on my laptop and it is working perfectly fine for me. Can you recheck your internet connection? If still facing the issue, you can refer to the answers of this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn't understand post.

Comment: Internet connection is ok, and from cmd I can ping any address by name and by ip.