# HibernateException when trying connect from Docker to external MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, docker

I created small app what is using Hibernate and Spring boot. I have MySQL db on external server with some `123.123.12.123` IP address.

When I run this app **locally** (on Windows) via `java -jar myapp.jar` there is **no** problem, app is starting and **everything is ok**. The **problem is appear** when I am try run this app in Docker. App even not start. There is HibernateException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I am sure it is because I cannot connect to db. (I have same issue when I was trying connect locally and db was not available). So what should I do to fix it? This is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://123.123.12.123:3306/szoplist_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=my_passwd
```

**EDIT:**

I am running docker image via `docker run -p 8080:8080 <IMAGE_ID>`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE

ADD ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Another apps (without db) with the same Dockerfile and run command works.

Comment: Please specify your `docker run` command. Docker file of your app might also help. Did you try to ping the ip from the container? You can also try one of the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/q/20430371/2065796

Comment: Yes, sir! Done.

Comment: I have internet in my docker toolbox - I can ping to my `123.123.12.123` server(as `docker@192.168.99.100`).

Comment: What do you mean by `as docker@192.168.99.100`? Does `docker run -it openjdk:8-jdk-alpine ping 123.123.12.123` work?

Comment: `ping 123.123.12.123` works. `123.123.12.123` it is only IP of my external MySQL server. Docker what I use is locally on my PC.

Comment: And yes, `docker run -it openjdk:8-jdk-alpine ping 123.123.12.123` works.

Comment: It might be that the problem is in hibernate setup. Make sure that the correct spring profile gets picked in docker (the correct `application.properties`). Does the exception have `caused by` sections? Posting full stack-trace might also help.