# Unable to connect to internal network from inside the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package.json /tmp/
RUN npm config set registry http://xxx:8081/repository/npm-group/
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . /opt/app/
RUN cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app/

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I try to build an image using:

```
docker build -t blah .
```

All goes well until I get to step 5/10, npm install. The logs show:

```
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://xxx:8081/repository/npm-group/prop-types failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:8081
```

I have no idea what is happening. The Nexus repository is hosted on the internal network, so I have no idea why it cannot be contacted.

Iptables shows the following:

```
philippe@laptop:~/localdev/react-starterkit$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate  RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your "internal network" one to which your host is directly connected, or is it accessible via some sort of VPN?

Comment: are you able to ping this inside container ? `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` and `ping <your-nexus-ip>` also share the output of `telnet <your-nexus-ip> 8081`

Comment: @larsks I am directly connected via wired connection. I can access Nexus from my host. I cannot build the image so I cannot run the container and perform the ping command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644890/2122950
The DNS of my company was not present in /etc/resolv.conf