# How to get access to the API in the container that the host have access to but a container doesn't?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My host has access to the API but when I enter docker container it doesn't. I've already added DNS to docker daemon

The host I want to access is an external API working on 80 port
I want to connect to it via CURL

When I do PING from my host I get responses
When I do PING from container I get `unknown host`

My networking is set to bridge.

I was thinking about setting up the proxy but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Assuming the API you are trying to reach is external to your HOST or other containers, this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet may be helpful

Comment: @piy26 thank you for response, my container has access to the Internet and to nameservers as well which I specified in daemon.json

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use `network_mode: host` in your `docker-compose.yml`. This is great as long as you use a singe container, but if you want several to communicate, bridge is better.

See here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers

Comment: I know about it but unfortunately it doesn't work on Mac.