# How to build go modules in docker?

Tags: docker, go, go-modules

I'm trying to build my go project in the docker container.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12.9 as builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o encashment


FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/encashment /encashment/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/encashment"]
```

I have only one dependency in go.mod:

```
require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
```

If I delete `gorilla/mux` locally and call `go mod download`, everyhing works fine. But when I call `docker build .` it returns

```
go: finding github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
go: github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.3: unknown revision v1.7.3
go: error loading module requirements
```

How to make this work?
**UPD:** Here is the piece of tcpdump output:

```
19:00:00.220102 IP 172.17.0.2.43627 > dns.google.domain: 15472+ A? github.com. (28)
19:00:00.220115 IP 172.17.0.2.43627 > dns.google.domain: 64629+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
19:00:02.969391 IP 172.17.0.1.38261 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 172
19:00:03.971322 IP 172.17.0.1.38261 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 172
19:00:04.971794 IP 172.17.0.1.38261 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 172
19:00:05.221952 IP 172.17.0.2.40395 > dns.google.domain: 15472+ A? github.com. (28)
19:00:05.221992 IP 172.17.0.2.40395 > dns.google.domain: 64629+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
19:00:05.970002 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:05.970263 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:05.972573 IP 172.17.0.1.38261 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 172
19:00:06.971288 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:06.971446 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:08.972581 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:08.972736 IP 172.17.0.1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? _googlecast._tcp.local. (40)
19:00:10.224125 IP 172.17.0.2.43627 > dns.google.domain: 15472+ A? github.com. (28)
19:00:10.224171 IP 172.17.0.2.43627 > dns.google.domain: 64629+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
```

Comment: Tried to replicate but it worked on my Docker build:


> Step 6/12 : RUN go mod download
> go: finding github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
> Step 7/12 : COPY . .

Are you sure your Docker Engine has internet access denied due to proxy settings?

Comment: @prometherion I don't know how to check this for sure, but I've added `tcpdump -i docker0` output

Comment: Thanks for the `go mod download` after only copying .mod and .sum I was re-fetching deps like crazy. Now the cache works.

Answer (score 3):

Well, thanks to @prometherion The problem was in the absence of internet access from within of docker container. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431030/11901987) worked for me. Guess that I should  create an issue in golang repo and ask to rework this error message.

Comment: great, glad you solved :)
please put a +1 on my comment since you found useful!