# docker dns failing with custom dns on host

Tags: docker, dns

i'm trying to set up pihole in a docker container (on a raspberry pi) and as such, have my DNS on my ip: 192.160.170.10. The docker container runs the dns and exposes its port 53, where the dns is available

when running `iplookup google.com` on the host, i get the correct output:

```
Server:         192.160.170.10 
Address:        192.160.170.10#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.16.78
```

My resolv.conf also contains this address.
when running a docker container, i am unable to do this nslookup however:

`docker run busybox nslookup google.com`
outputs:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

[Following this tutorial](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) i've tried specifying the dns with the following command:

```
docker run --dns 192.160.170.10 busybox  nslookup google.com
```

but this also does not solve the problem. I've also tried adding the dns to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, which also does nothing.
the docker container's `resolv.conf` output is: `nameserver 192.160.170.10`

**What is wrong with my configuration / How can i further debug this DNS issue?**

edit:
output from `docker run --rm --net=host busybox nslookup google.com`:

```
Server:        192.160.170.10
Address:       192.160.170.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.16.78

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

Comment: Have you tried with a DNS that surely resolves google.com(`docker run --rm --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com`)? If this still does not work, you may try to ping or telnet the nameserver to check if it is reachable. _;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached_ suggests that the resolver is not reachable. You may try to reset everything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431030/13736525

Comment: i can `ping 8.8.8.8` from the container, but i can't connect with `--dns 8.8.8.8 nslookup google.com`
Since i'm on a raspberry pi i can't use the link to reset my network. I've already tried it with a docker system prune though. I can also `ping google.com` though and it will resolve (but nslookup won't work)

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you try to run `docker run --rm --net=host busybox nslookup google.com`?

Comment: i've added the command and response to the answer (because formatting).

Comment: I guess the problem is in the docker-bridge network(perhaps in the iptables rules that should do the translation from the docker-bridge outside and vice-versa). If you are running the container directly on the host network(raspberry) it looks fine. Perhaps 53 is blocked somehow. Not easy to reproduce

Comment: do you have any ideas on how i can test this? I'm confused as to why i get the output `can't find google.com: no answer` with `--net=host`

Comment: Seems that busybox has a problem with IPv6. Try `docker run -ti --rm --net=host alpine nslookup google.com` or query ipv4 only `docker run -ti --rm --net=host busybox nslookup -query=A google.com`