# Flask API Web Scrape Using Selenium Chrome Driver in Docker Containers

Tags: python, docker, selenium, flask

Selenium Grid Server works on port *4444* and I want another container for Flask API that would use Selenium Chrome Driver to scrape websites.

Flask API works outside of the Docker container but when I build Docker container it gives urllib3 Exceptions:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd542587760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

**Selenium Chrome Container:**

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-yttrium
```

**Flask API:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def title():
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    driver.close()

    return driver.title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y curl python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils
RUN curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
    python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall && \
    rm get-pip.py
RUN pip3 install -U selenium

RUN apt-get update -y


WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT  ["python3"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: It seems like your container has no Internet access

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: This issue seems to be solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Comment: I think internet seems to be working because inside container bash if I "apt-get update
" it fetch and read the packages.