# Error building Node/NPM Angular image on Docker

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I tried many ways to solve this problem, but it's not working.
I have an angular app, I created a Dockerfile with the code below:

```
FROM node:latest AS ng-builder
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod


FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=ng-builder /app/dist/sca-front /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

My application works well when running "ng s". But when I create an image on Docker, it doesn't work. I have no proxy, no vpn, a good internet connection...

These errors/warnings are shown:

```
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.3 -> 7.0.7
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.7>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.7` to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/binary-extensions/-/binary-extensions-1.13.1.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-01T01_24_40_819Z-debug.log
```

I tried call "RUN npm RUN npm install -g npm@7.0.7" because of version of angular...but it looks like an timeout. I tried change the npm version on docker...but it doesn't work.

I tried the dockerfile in a new/small project, it's working. But in a bigger project...

Comment: why dont you run `ng build` outside of the container in a shell script and then in your docker file just have `FROM nginx` onwards and copy the angular build directory to nginx html. This way you dont need to have a node build done in docker at all.

Comment: I would search for things like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet

Comment: @Abe I could do this, but in many languages and technologies, the  good way is to build the application due to CI/CD. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @Ben W, actually, the internet works, but maybe there is a timeout

Comment: @Dockerizandu good approach for the CI/CD, nevertheless you want repeatable builds. Copy both the package.json and the package-lock.json in the image and try using `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.

Comment: Interesting. I will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced an error similar to this while trying to create a container on Docker for my react app.
I solved it using the `node:14-apline` for the base image and installed `npm@latest` just before installing  packages.

Note: You can decide to install `npm@7` instead.

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install npm@latest

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2031#issuecomment-715935308

Comment: I will test soon and I will give you a feedback! Thanks

Comment: Great! I'll be looking to forward to knowing how if it works out.