# Docker container ping 100% packet loss on mac desktop. No VPN

Tags: macos, docker

I am new to docker so this may be a very basic issue.
I am attempting to ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) using a sh with the busybox image.

The command used is

```
docker run -it busybox sh
/ # ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.210.196): 56 data bytes
```

After I stop the process the output is:

--- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) ping statistics ---
65 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

from terminal ping returns the expected results:

```
ping www.google.com
```

output
PING [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (216.58.211.164): 56 data bytes

64 bytes from 216.58.211.164: icmp_seq=0 ttl=116 time=15.127 ms

64 bytes from 216.58.211.164: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=13.711 ms

64 bytes from 216.58.211.164: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=20.603 ms

64 bytes from  216.58.211.164: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=13.303 ms

I am running docker on a MacBook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Comment: No from the docker I can build the application so it is able to download npm. It only applies when attempting to ping from the shell

Comment: @ChrisHunter-Johnson Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same with version 20.10.17.

Comment: I changed to using docker compose and the issue is no longer present