# why docker container has internet problem?

Tags: docker, devops

We have several containers that all use the same network.  When we put the value of iptables: false in the daemon.json file, the Internet of containers is connected and works well.  But apart from the domain, we will have access through ip and port.  But we only want to connect via domain.  When we clear iptables:false, we only have access through the domain, but the containers lose access to the Internet.

resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

network details:

[show network details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud6nO.jpg)

```
drive: bridge
scope: local
attachable: true
internal: false
ipv4 subnet - 172.25.0.0/16: ipv4 geteway - 172.25.0.1
ipv4 ip range: ipv4 excluded ips
```

We tested different methods.  Almost most of the methods in this link.

[My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Please someone who is an expert in docker and ubuntu help us.