# Unable to call OpenAI API from within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, openai-api

I am trying to call the OpenAI API from within my docker container but the request is timing out. The same curl works on my machine but not from within my container

I tried running this curl. It worked on the host machine but not in the container.

```
  curl https://api.openai.com/v1/models \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer sk-auth-token' \
  -H 'OpenAI-Organization: org-orgid'
```

Here is my Dockerfile. Please let me know what I am missing here. Also, I'd like to add that I am able to call it sometimes but other times it timeouts.

```
FROM python:3.12.0a3-alpine3.17 as base

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    build-base \
    postgresql-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    python3-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    musl-dev \
    libpq \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && find /usr/local \
    \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
    -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
    -exec rm -rf '{}' +

# Now multistage builds
FROM python:3.12.0a3-alpine3.17

RUN apk add --update --no-cache libpq libjpeg-turbo

COPY --from=base /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/
COPY --from=base /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONPATH /app:$PYTHONPATH

COPY . /app/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)