# Docker Container don't have network access

Tags: docker, server, dns, connectivity, ubuntu-22.04

I have rented a VPS Linux VC4-8 server from Strato and would like to deploy a few Docker containers on it.
Unfortunately, the deployed containers do not have internet access or cannot resolve DNS.
As a result, I can't run commands like `RUN apk update`
in the build process.

I have already tried various solutions, but unfortunately without success. Here are a few threads that I have already read and tried:

- [My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers
- https://forums.docker.com/t/no-internet-access-in-the-docker-containers/108223
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445229/no-network-access-from-within-docker-container

The following is an example of my problem starting from a completely clean server (Ubuntu 22.04):

1. `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping google.com` works flawlessly (on the host)
2. Install Docker using the official [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) (Install using the apt repository)
3. Run `docker pull alpine` and `docker run --rm -it alpine:latest`
4. Attach to the alpine Container

   1. ```
      PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
      ^C
      --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
      30 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
      ```
   2. ```
      / # ping google.com
      ping: bad address 'google.com'
      ```

I also tried these steps on another server (from Hetzner) and everything worked normally there.
The files, such as `/etc/resolv.conf` look almost the same on both servers.

resolv.conf on the Strato Server:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53 
options edns0 trust-ad 
search .
```

resolv.conf on the Hetzner Server

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

The default 'bridge' network looks exactly the same when I run `docker inspect bridge`.
And when I compare the Container from both machines with `docker inspect <container name>` everything looks the same. Only the `CgroupnsMode` property is set to `host` on the running example and to `private` on the Strato Server (but I am not sure if this is a problem regarding the connectivity).

If I start the container with the `--network host` option, I can successfully set up the containers and also access the internet from inside the containers, but after that my Django container cannot find the Postgres container. I also think that this is not the preferred way to do this.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason that I have these problems with Docker on the Strato server?
I really don't know what else to try.

Thanks in advance for any help!

br, Brian

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it is a problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and Docker.... I hope anybody has a reason for this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the docker forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-bridge-networking-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-22-04/136326/6

> The problem is netplan, ubuntu 22.04 use netplan to adress ip via
> DHCP. You need to modify the file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and
> add en in front of the * :
>
> ```
> network:
>     ethernets:
>         all:
>             dhcp4: true
>             dhcp6: true
>             match:
>                 name: 'en*'
>     renderer: networkd
>     version: 2
> ```
>
> this will force netplan to use DHCP only on interface en* and the
> docker interface is docker0
>
> next apply the configuration and restart network:
>
> ```
> netplan apply
> sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
>
> #Docker need to be restarted to request a new ip
> sudo systemctl restart docker
> ```

Worked for my Strato V-Server with ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thx! Thats the reason!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! After adjusting in the file everything works perfectly.

Comment: I seem to have lost connectivity to my remote server after netplan apply : )

Comment: Without knowledge, what you've done, you can't get any help. If should I guess, your network device-name is not starting with "en" like `enp2s0`.