# Cron job to restart network ONLY if it's down?

Tags: networking, cron

I've had frustrating issues with a computer whose network drops at apparently random times and as a work-around I made a simple cron job to restart it every hour.  But this seems silly if the network is already up -- why restart it, right?

So is there a simple script I could create that will first check (ping?  ifconfig?) to see if the network is working and then only restart if that returns false?  Or a flag on network-manager that will check itself?

My cron is just this:

```
15 * * * * /sbin/service network-manager restart
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with ideas on how best to "network-manage" this!  (pun intended!)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a more complicated script from your crontab:

```
15 * * * * mySafeRestart


#!/bin/bash  
# mySafeRestart : restart only if uncommunicative
if ! ping -c 1 remote.host.com ; then 
    /sbin/service network-manager restart
fi
```

As for a test for network up, see [How to test an Internet connection with bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-a-internet-connection-in-bash)

Using the netcat test suggested below would be:

```
if ! nc -w 2 google.com 80 ; then
  ...
```

Comment: I've seen network connections where a ping works but TCP and UDP packets just cannot make it. I would suggest using `nc` or some such tool to check the network.

Comment: Hi @AlexisWilke, thanks for the comment.  Can you offer a similar solution using nc?  I had something like the above in mind but if there are serious problems with ping then maybe that's less than ideal.  I am not a programmer so any help with that side would be great.

Comment: @user1149499, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922943/test-from-shell-script-if-remote-tcp-port-is-open#9463554

Comment: Can I replace the "if ! ping..." line with "if nc -w 2 -v google.com 80 ; then..."?  Or is there other syntax for this I need to consider?  And would it always be port 80?

Comment: nc versus ping versus ifconfig is more of a question of how you determine if your network is up.  There's lots of ways to handle it.  If I was using the `nc` in the cron job, I'd drop the `-v`.  Testing `if  nc -w 2  google.com 80   ; then echo "up" ; fi`  looks like the syntax would be fine.