# Testing computer connectivity with Bash

Tags: bash, connection

Being a noob, I can't comment, so posting a question to expand on the answers for this thread; [How to test an Internet connection with bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-an-internet-connection-with-bash#comment58388451_932187)

for Mac users.

The -w1 or -w 1 option specified in the answers does not work on Mac
However, -W1 or -W 1 does work. It is a case sensitivity issue for the Mac rather than an invalid/unavailable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac: I assume you need a timeout? What's wrong with using the `-t` option (timeout) ?

A script for this, adapted from your link:

```sh
checkInternet () {
    error=$(ping -q  -t1 -c1 "8.8.8.8" 2>&1 >"/dev/null" || true)

    if [ "${error}" != "" ]; then
        echo "No internet" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Internet" >&2
}

checkInternet
```

Comment: Nice Idea! Using the info from the link I had put this together to check connectivity in the local system

```
if ping -q -W 1 -c 1 $1> /dev/null; then
        echo "$1 connected"
    else
        echo "$1 offline"        
    fi
```